# Does the Logitech MK235 work with a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, hardware

Next week, I am going to buy a Raspberry Pi 3 and I want to buy a mouse and a keyboard with the Pi.

Can anybody please tell me if the Logitech MK235 works with the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 2):

Really this is mostly an operating system issue, and not a brand-of-my-computer issue. Presuming you are using Raspbian or some other [GNU/Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) variant, the OS kernel (which is what implements hardware drivers) is one which is used on tens of millions of normal workstations and laptops.

That looks like a pretty standard wireless keyboard/mouse combo ("Fullsize, durable, simple").  USB HID (human interface device) protocols are standardized, and anything like that will be fine.  There's only a potential issue when you get into zany mice with 42 buttons and lots of special features that require a proprietary driver.  That Logitech product does not fall into such a category.  I've used piles of Logitech HID ware with linux over the years including wireless keyboard/mouse combos.

In other words yes, I promise it will work with the Pi 3.

Note that by default Raspbian uses a UK keyboard layout.  Because of this you will notice a few keys don't print what they are supposed to.  To fix this, when you first turn the Pi on, you should be presented with a program called `raspi-config` which lets you set various options (if not, just run `sudo raspi-config` at the command line).  The fourth option of the main menu should be "Localisation Options".  Choose that, then "Change Keyboard Layout" and select a US 104 key PC keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

[eLinux](https://elinux.org) host a list of [RPi compatible devices](https://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals).

There are separate lists for [RPi USB Keyboards](https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Keyboards) and  [RPi USB Mouse devices](https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Mouse_devices).

Comment: thanks for the answer but the mk235 isn't in the list

Comment: That list is very unlikely to be complete WRT things like keyboards and mice.  Really this is mostly an operating system issue, and not a brand-of-my-computer issue.

Answer (score 1):

While attempting to use the MK 360 combo with my rPi Zero W I have discovered that:
-- if the receiver is attached directly via OTG Cable both the keyboard and mouse
work no matter what
-- however, if I connect the receiver through a cheapie 4-port USB hub (with power),
I have to have both the keyboard and mouse powered up before booting the 
rPi Zero W.
-- upon boot and verification that the combo is working, I can switch power off
on the mouse and keyboard and everything works fine if I power up the combo
at a later time
So maybe if a particular Logitech (or any brand for that matter) Wireless 
keyboard, mouse, or combo is playing tricks with you, see if following the
above pattern helps...
'best of luck,