# Supporting Wireless Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

Which wireless keyboard is suitable for Raspberry pi?

Now am using the zebronics wireless keyboard and mouse combo it is not working properly

Is Logitech MK220 Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo compatible with raspbian jessie

Comment: I have been using Microsoft, Rappo, Logictech and other brands for a couple of years.  I found Logitech most compatible with Rpi 1/2/3/4.  For me Logitech has the  best value for money.  I have been using K520 for R[i3B and Rpi4B (stretch and buster) for a year so.  I found everything OK, all default setting are good.  I am also using K545 for Acer PC Win 10 but found it not so matching Rpi.  I once used high grade Logitech for gamers, twice as expensive, but I don't find them worth my money (key too sensitive, key tops easy to fall off, ...) In short, cheap grade Logitech good for poor guys.

Comment: I remember I once bought MK220, which is the cheapest I used.  But I found the keys a bit heavy, so I replaced it with the MK5xx which is twice as expensive but good value for money.  To conclude, MK220 is OK for casual users, MK5xx is for frequent users, and MK7xx for non professional gamers, ..

Answer (score 3):

The [eLinux Wiki](https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Keyboards) lists USB keyboards that users have found to be compatible with the Pi. The MK220 is listed.

Other posts that may be relevant:

- [Will the RPi-4 work with a Logitech K830 keyboard?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103797/will-the-rpi-4-work-with-a-logitech-k830-keyboard)
- [Does the Logitech MK235 work with a Raspberry Pi 3?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78645/does-the-logitech-mk235-work-with-a-raspberry-pi-3/)